# How to reduce noise for arduino capacitive sensing

Tags: arduino, transformer, noise, capacitance

I have an artistically-painted 5mm-thick wood panel that I want to use as a light switch without alteration to the image. My solution was to (try to) make a specific region on the panel touch-sensitive using an arduino and the CapSense library, and use a relay for switching.

I connected the capacitive sensing wire to a piece of aluminum foil taped directly behind the region of the wood panel that I wanted to be touch-sensitive. I got this to work perfectly when the arduino was powered by my laptop, but when I connected it to my cheap 5v 700mA power supply, which was connected to main, the noise was too much.

After reading a little on noise reduction, I tried connecting a 1000uf capacitor in parallel with the transformer -> arduino line. That seemed to help, but still was far from fixing the problem.

This is where I'm stuck. I ordered more capacitors, but figured I'd post the problem while I wait. Is more capacitance the answer, and if so, how much? Are there other tricks / common practices for removing transformer noise that seem like they'd probably be useful here? Or should I be using a different method of capacitive sensing than the digital delay-based CapSense library?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, your 5V 700mA transformer you mention is a power supply? I would recommend getting a different power supply with lower noise. There's a reason the one you got was cheap, and it's not that you got a good deal.

Comment: Yeah, a cheap small power supply. How can I tell what power supplies are higher quality? I also have the restriction that all the circuitry needs to be small enough to fit in the wall circuit box for the light switch it'll be replacing. My "wall wart" sized transformer fits, but not sure if something higher quality would also be bigger.

Comment: Look to the specs if you can. Seek ones with good line rejection. If you want commercial off-the-shelf devices it might be harder, though, since many companies sell things that are just good enough. Apple's phone chargers, for instance, are good enough to charge phones but might be a problem for anything noise-sensitive like that. Perhaps get a linear+switching supply; those tend to be low-noise while not sacrificing too much efficiency.